# Capturing an array of vectors in a lambda: possible GCC bug?

Tags: c++, gcc, vector, lambda, c++14

This program fails to compile with *GCC 5.3* (`g++ -std=c++14`):

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v[] = {std::vector<int>(10), std::vector<int>(10)};

    auto lambda = [v]{};
}
```

reporting the error:

```
file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
file.cpp:7:20: internal compiler error: in build_special_member_call, at cp/call.c:7789
  auto lambda = [v]{};
                    ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://bugs.archlinux.org/> for instructions.
```

I've tried with *clang* and it compiles successfully ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab92b1c8b324a9cc)).

Is this program well formed? May this be a GCC bug?

Comment: "*internal compiler error*" is a compiler bug

Comment: By the way: g++ 4.8.4 compiles it nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC has explicitly told you this is a bug, and how you should go about reporting this:

```
file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
file.cpp:7:20: internal compiler error: in build_special_member_call, at cp/call.c:7789
  auto lambda = [v]{};
                    ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://bugs.archlinux.org/> for instructions.
```

I can confirm that the same error happens on a vanilla GCC 5, so please raise a bug at `http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html` You may also want to mention that the bug occurs on trunk (also confirmed). It is a regression from GCC 4.9.

Comment: It looks like someone (maybe you) has already raised the bug at: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70494

Comment: No, it wasn't me, but I've added a comment :) (and so you)